# How to make this script to stop Repainting in Renko charts

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

Is there a way to make non repaint HTF Renko charts? Whenever the real time charts plots it is different after reloading the same in Renko charts.

This script is not repainting in Normal candlesticks but it is repainting in RENKO Candlesticks.

If the higher timeframe produces more bricks, then this script repaints massively.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='HTF Renko', overlay=true)

//HTF CANDLES 
ht = input('60', 'Timeframe')
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => 
     request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 

Htfclose = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, ht, close)
plot(Htfclose, color=color.green, title='HTF Close')

//Signals
buy = close > Htfclose and barstate.isconfirmed
sell =  close < Htfclose and barstate.isconfirmed

//Plots
plotshape(buy, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny)
```

How to make this script a non repaint one in Renko Charts?

Comment: The Pine Script v5 Reference Manual states "It is NOT recommended to use barstate.isconfirmed in request.security expression. Its value requested from request.security is unpredictable. Please note that using this variable/function can cause indicator repainting."

Try with barstate.islast

Comment: Thank you. But if I try with barstate.islast no signals are showing. I think Renko can't get the previous bar with time.